# How to replace multiple strings in a class list in python?

Tags: python, loops, jupyter-notebook, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I have a list of tweet that contains hundreds of tweets. I want to replace the nonstandard words in the list of tweets with their standard equivalents by looping through the tweets.

I used this code to read the file containing the standard words

```
dk = open('Aword.txt','r')
dlist = []
for x in dk.readlines():
    dlist.append(x.replace('\n',''))

dlist
```

then I use this code to print words that are not in the list

```
standard = dlist
tweets = df


for idx, tweet in enumerate(tweets):
    for word in tweet.split():
        if word.lower() in equivalences:
            tweet = tweet.replace(word, equivalences[word.lower()])
    tweets[idx] = tweet

print(tweets)
```

this is what the dataframe containing the tweets looks like:
[tweets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5m9R.png)

this is what the dict containing the standard words looks like:
[dlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X02kb.png)

but it is limited to printing only the first five strings, I'm looking for a way to print all of the strings without limititations (flexible to the numbers of strings in each tweets). Thank you for your help:)

Comment: Have you tried apply another for loop over `dlist`?

Comment: Can you show a snippet of the `standard_word.txt` file? And what make a tweet word nonstandard?

Comment: do you mean like nested loop? if yes, I haven't

Comment: standard_word.txt contains a list of words from the english dictionary, what I meant by non standards are words you won't find in the dictionary, like slangs

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood you correctly,
but did you mean something like this:

```
equivalences = {"jst": "just"}
tweets = ['This is jst a random tweet']

for id, tweet in enumerate(tweets):
    for word in tweet.split():
        if word.lower() in list(equivalences.keys()):
            tweet = tweet.replace(word, equivalences[word])
    tweets[id] = tweet

print(tweets)
```

Comment: in your code, it will only print the slang words, but what I meant to do is to replace the slang words with formal words

Comment: Updated my example, check it out now.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to replace non-standard words, you can do it using an equivalence dictionary...

**EDIT**: Code changed to use only 'equivalences' dictionary!

```
equivalences = {"jst": "just", "stp":"stop"}
tweets = ['This is jst a random tweet', 'Stp it now']


for idx, tweet in enumerate(tweets):
    for word in tweet.split():
        if word.lower() in equivalences:
            tweet = tweet.replace(word, equivalences[word.lower()])
    tweets[idx] = tweet

print(tweets)
```

Comment: thank you, but this is not exactly what I meant. I have a class list of tweets that still contains slangs in them and I want to replace the slangs with their equivalences that I already compiled in a dictionary. in your example, I only need 'tweets' and 'equivalences'. and when I tried using your code it gave an error "argument of type 'type' is not iterable"

Comment: May be now it meets your needs...

Comment: **ADVICE**: This is the fastest and direct way to check a key existence in a dictionary __*word.lower() in equivalences*__:-)   can be significant when processing hundreds of tweets

Comment: I tried to change the code using my data but there is no change in the result. I made these changes to assign the data 
"equivalences = dict" (dict contains the dictionary I made to store the words and their equivalences)
tweets = df (df is a dataframe containing the tweets with slangs that I want to check and replace)

Comment: Don't worry. Add a sample of your data and show the piece off your code (edit post) and I'll try to help you.

Comment: edited my questin 2 days ago but somehow my comment got deleted

Comment: It looks like your "dlist" only includes standard terms. So, what are the terms to substitute? How can you recognize non-standard terms in tweets?
To replace bad terms in tweets, in my opinion, you need a dictionary with the non-standard terms (dictionary keys) and their standard equivalences (dictionary values). My code reflects that.